# Place Autocomplete in iOS (swift) on Signup (address) form

Tags: ios, swift, google-places-api, autocompletetextview, street-address

I am a signup form which has bunch of text fields like name, phone, address 1st line, city, state etc.

Can I use [googles's Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete) on this form in such a way that when I start typing address 1st line in one of the fields it suggests/auto completes and fills the city and state

1st question, is it possible, if yes are there any examples or tutorials?

There are examples out there but they use autocomplete UI, I want to be able to use my own edit text fields.

Comment: yes it is possible..just request to google places api which gives you all the information of places in response and you insert those response e.g. address,city,street, to the textfields.

Comment: @anishparajuli do you know any examples or code snippents

Comment: yeah sure https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So Yes I was able to do exactly what I wanted.

I had two dependencies for this.
1. [AutoComplete Text Field](https://github.com/mnbayan/AutocompleteTextfieldSwift)
2. [Google's Place AutoComplete](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete#get_place_predictions_programmatically)